# Replacing a solid green region with another image with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

The image below has a green region that I'm looking to replace with any other image. It's not necessary for its perspective to match.

[image]

I've been able to create a mask. But haven't really been successful with resizing and aligning the other image to this one with the green region. Most resources I've found online mention both images' need for the same size, but I'm only looking to resize the new image to fit inside the green rectangle instead of having two square images overlapping with one of them with a cutout.

[image]

What's a good approach here?

Comment: Get the 4 corners of the image to be inserted and the 4 corners of your green region. Then do a perspective warp and composite the two images. Search Google and you will find examples. Do the reverse of https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/25/4-point-opencv-getperspective-transform-example/, for example.

Comment: Since you already have your mask image, you can obtain the bouncing box and use Numpy slicing to extract/replace the ROI

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is one solution using Python OpenCV.

```
Read both images.

Measure and enter 4 corresponding sets of x,y control points.

Compute homography (perspective coefficients)

Warp the source image using the homography -- the background will be black

Create a binary mask from the dst image using the green color range.

Invert the mask.

Apply the inverted mask to the dst image to blacken the inside of the region of interest (where the src will go)

Add the warped src to the masked dst to form the result
```

src:

[image]

dst:

[image]

```
#!/python3.7

import cv2
import numpy as np


# Read source image.
src = cv2.imread('original.jpg')

# Four corners of source image
# Coordinates are in x,y system with x horizontal to the right and y vertical downward
# listed clockwise from top left
pts_src = np.float32([[0, 0], [325, 0], [325, 472], [0, 472]])


# Read destination image.
dst = cv2.imread('green_rect.png')

# Four corners of destination image.
pts_dst = np.float32([[111, 59], [206, 60], [216, 215], [121, 225]])

# Calculate Homography if more than 4 points
# h = forward transformation matrix
#h, status = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)

# Alternate if only 4 points
h = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(pts_src,pts_dst)


# Warp source image to destination based on homography
# size argument is width x height, so have to reverse shape values
src_warped = cv2.warpPerspective(src, h, (dst.shape[1],dst.shape[0]))


# Set BGR color ranges
lowerBound = np.array([0, 255, 0]);
upperBound = np.array([0, 255, 0]);

# Compute mask (roi) from ranges in dst
mask = cv2.inRange(dst, lowerBound, upperBound);

# Dilate mask, if needed, when green border shows
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
mask = cv2.dilate(mask,kernel,iterations = 1)

# Invert mask
inv_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

# Mask dst with inverted mask
dst_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(dst, dst, mask=inv_mask)

# Put src_warped over dst
result = cv2.add(dst_masked, src_warped)

# Save outputs
cv2.imwrite('warped_src.jpg', src_warped)
cv2.imwrite('inverted_mask.jpg', inv_mask)
cv2.imwrite('masked_dst.jpg', dst_masked)
cv2.imwrite('perspective_composite.jpg', result)
```

warped_src:

[image]

inverted_mask:

[image]

masked_dst:

[image]

result:

[image]

I will leave it to the reader to filter the excess green border or edit the control points in the dst image to make the region of interest larger.

Note: if the aspect ratio of the src does not match that of the green rectangle, then the src will get distorted with this method.

Comment: This is fantastic work and definitely a good approach to the problem, so thank you for the effort. Unfortunately, I think I was looking for something a bit different. I was trying to find a way to align the image around the center of the bounding box above (in blue outline) and only show the parts of the image which aren't covered by the mask. Maybe this picture below will better illustrate what I'm saying.  
https://i.imgur.com/DRw05z9.png  
  
No need to match perspective, because the green area may not be rectangular at all times so it'd complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

Per request in comments to my previous answer doing it in perspective, here is one way to do it with a simple scale and translation affine warp.

```
Read both images

Measure the height of the green region and get the height of the src image

Measure the center (x,y) of the green region and get the center of the src image

Compute the affine matrix coefficients for scale and translation only (no rotation or skew)

Warp the source image using the affine matrix -- the background will be black

Create a binary mask from the warped src image making everything not black into white

Invert the mask

Apply the inverted mask to the dst image

Add the warped src over the masked dst to form the result
```

src:

[image]

dst:

[image]

```
#!/python3.7

import cv2
import numpy as np


# Read source image.
src = cv2.imread('original.jpg')
h_src, w_src = src.shape[:2]

# Read destination image.
dst = cv2.imread('green_rect.png')
h_dst, w_dst = dst.shape[:2]

# compute scale from height of src and height of green region
h_green=170
scale = h_green/h_src

# compute offsets from center of scaled src and center of green
x_src = (scale)*w_src/2
y_src = (scale)*h_src/2
x_green = 165
y_green = 140
xoff = (x_green - x_src)
yoff = (y_green - y_src)

# build affine matrix for scale and translate only
affine_matrix = np.float32([ [scale,0,xoff], [0,scale,yoff] ])

# do affine warp
# add 1 to src to ensure no pure black
src_warped = cv2.warpAffine(src+1, affine_matrix, (w_dst, h_dst), cv2.INTER_AREA)

# Compute mask (roi) in warped src
_, mask = cv2.threshold(src_warped,1,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Invert single channel of mask
inv_mask = cv2.bitwise_not(mask[:,:,0])

# Mask dst with inverted mask
dst_masked = cv2.bitwise_and(dst, dst, mask=inv_mask)

# Put warped src over masked dst
result = cv2.add(dst_masked,src_warped)

# Save outputs
cv2.imwrite('warped_src.jpg', src_warped)
cv2.imwrite('masked_src.jpg', mask)
cv2.imwrite('affine_composite.jpg', result)
```

warped_src:

[image]

inverted mask:

[image]

masked dst

[image]

result:

[image]